# Old Cartoon Network anime, rival has a spaceship slightly better than the protagonist's and they know how many more hits it takes to destroy a ship

Tags: story-identification, anime

Lately I’ve been trying to remember an anime I think was on Cartoon Network. It was definitely a space anime.

I remember the protagonist had a weird looking ship and he also had a rival with a similar, slightly better ship maybe?

I also remember somehow they knew how many hits it would take destroy a ship.

What I remember from the only scene I can remember is that maybe they were one persons ships but I remember a ship with more than one person stating it would take a certain amount of hits to destroy one. But I could be wrong.

Also I’m pretty sure the ships looked weird but it’s such an old memory.

Comment: Okay, that helps. How long ago did you see this show? Can you describe the shapes of the ships or say what the characters looked like? Any detail you can think of, no matter how minor it seems, could be the key.

Comment: I think the show you are describing is SWAT Kats: The Radical Squadron.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAT_Kats:_The_Radical_Squadron

Comment: Do you know if any mech were involved? Could this possibly be part of the Gundam Wing series? CN aired those during their Toonami programming slots during the late-90s/early-00s.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it was during the daytime Toonami block or the Adult Swim block?

Answer (score 2):

I think the show you are describing is [*SWAT Kats: The Radical Squadron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAT_Kats:_The_Radical_Squadron).

> Using discarded military parts and weapons from the salvage yard, Jake and Chance built themselves a three-engine jet fighter called the Turbokat, which resembled several different jet fighters, most notably the Grumman F-14 and the Saab Draken, along with a handful of other vehicles such as the Cyclotron (a motorcycle built into the jet's seating, deployed from the bomb bay of the Turbokat like a missile), the TurboMole (a subterranean vehicle used to drill underground), the HoverKat (a militarized hovercraft), and the Thunder Truck (a militarized Jeep modified from their tow truck). All these vehicles were stored, along with a training area and other equipment, in a secret hangar below the yard. Razor and T-Bone now patrol Megakat City as the SWAT Kats, defending it against any kind of menace that threatens the city. Their enemies include the criminal mastermind Dark Kat, the undead sorcerer Pastmaster, the mutant evil genius Doctor Viper, and the robotic gangsters the Metallikats. The SWAT Kats also face many villains-of-the-week, such as Madkat and Volcanus.

[image: SWAT Kats: The Radical Squadron poster]

Comment: The OP is asking specifically for a show based in space. I believe SWAT kats don't really fit the description.

Comment: @Stark07 there _was_ an episode where they were fighting aliens who were trying to steal the water from the planet, and the Turbo Cat had to achieve "speed of heat" to make it into space. But agreed, this wouldn't fit overall.

Comment: Was this cartoon done in _anime_ style, or was it a Western toon? If it was an anime, it **possibly** could be one of the _Gundam_ series

Comment: If it was an anime I bet you a dollar it was Outlaw Star.  One of the odd conceits of the show is that spaceships engage in hand-to-hand combat and look very strange.  The rival has a similarly odd ship.